# Improve Wiki for the `hypothesis-testing` tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [hypothesis-testing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hypothesis-testing) tag is quite popular yet has a very brief Wiki. Extending it could be helpful. Unfortunately, I do not think I am knowledgeable enough to do a good job at it myself. Let this post serve as an encouragement for someone who is.

Comment: Are you concerned about the excerpt or the full wiki?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica, mainly the full Wiki. If the excerpt can be improved alongside, it would of course be nice. (The [`tag-excerpt`](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-excerpt) tag I used was likely misleading, thus I have replaced it.)

Comment: The mischievous part of me wonders if the world would be a worse place if the tag disappeared. It is very unspecific.

Comment: @mdewey, I would not say it is *that* bad. We do not have tags to cover all possible tests, and sometimes the general one comes in quite handy. But this is just my impression.

Comment: @mdewey: There are enough questions on the general principles of hypothesis testing to justify its having its own tag; though I might question whether we need *hypothesis testing*, and *p-value*, and *statistical significance*.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica well I did say it was a bit mischievous. I agree though about the overlap with p-value and statistical significance.